# How do I find out what service is using a certain port?

Tags: windows-server-2008, port, services

Port 22 specifically. I installed freeSSHd on a [Windows Server 2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2008) box that only runs IIS. When I try to start the SSH Service, it tells me that the port is already being used. How can I find out what service is using this port?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Sysinternals TCPView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx) will show you TCP/UDP ports that are in use and the processes that are using them.

[image]

Comment: (An image-only answer isn't index-friendly :-)  TCPView, the tool shown, can be found here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx

Comment: @cwrea: Had trouble with the link -- fixed now.

Comment: +1 for Sysinternals. I've always used netstat -ab and it has worked for me but this is definitely better.

Answer (score 20):

`netstat -b` in the command prompt will also work. Sysinternals TCPView is basically a prettier GUI version, `netstat` is a tool that comes with Windows.

Sample output:

```
Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State           PID
  TCP    john:2817              localhost:2818         ESTABLISHED     972
  [firefox.exe]

  TCP    john:2818              localhost:2817         ESTABLISHED     972
  [firefox.exe]

  TCP    john:2821              localhost:2822         ESTABLISHED     972
  [firefox.exe]

  TCP    john:2822              localhost:2821         ESTABLISHED     972
  [firefox.exe]

  TCP    john:3177    peak-colo-196-219.peak.org:http  ESTABLISHED     972
  [firefox.exe]

  TCP    john:3182    peak-colo-196-219.peak.org:http  ESTABLISHED     972
  [firefox.exe]

  TCP    john:2879              67.69.247.70:http      CLOSE_WAIT      972
  [firefox.exe]

  TCP    john:2880              67.69.247.70:http      CLOSE_WAIT      972
  [firefox.exe]

  TCP    john:2881              67.69.247.70:http      CLOSE_WAIT      972
  [firefox.exe]

  TCP    john:2882              67.69.247.70:http      CLOSE_WAIT      972
  [firefox.exe]

  TCP    john:2883              67.69.247.70:http      CLOSE_WAIT      972
  [firefox.exe]

  TCP    john:2884              67.69.247.70:http      CLOSE_WAIT      972
  [firefox.exe]
```

Comment: Agreed, although I find the live-updating/highlighting in TCPView to be quite useful in tracking ports/processes down.

Comment: TCPView is better no doubt, although if he wants to avoid a download this is an alternative.

Comment: Yeah, definitely.

Comment: +1 For the simplicity but TCPView is better with it's GUI

Comment: +1 for the builtin solution.  "Use sysinternals" seems to be the answer to every Windows question here, but it's good to know how to solve problems without 3rd party software.

Comment: Casually I would use netstat -ano | findstr "port PORTNUMBER" but for something serious I would always use TCPview

Answer (score 3):

Take it to the next level with **[CurrPorts](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/cports.html)** by NirSoft:

> CurrPorts displays the list of all
>   currently opened TCP/IP and UDP ports
>   on your local computer. For each port
>   in the list, information about the
>   process that opened the port is also
>   displayed, including the process name,
>   full path of the process, version
>   information of the process (product
>   name, file description, and so on),
>   the time that the process was created,
>   and the user that created it.

Not only that but:

> In addition, CurrPorts allows you to
>   close unwanted TCP connections, kill
>   the process that opened the ports, and
>   save the TCP/UDP ports information to
>   HTML file , XML file, or to
>   tab-delimited text file. CurrPorts
>   also automatically mark with pink
>   color suspicious TCP/UDP ports owned
>   by unidentified applications
>   (Applications without version
>   information and icons)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

`netstat -an` will show all the ports which are currently open with their address in numerical form.
To find info about a particular port use via Power Shell's prompt as Administrator: `netstat -an | Select-String 10000`.

Answer (score 3):

netstat in Windows 2008:

Start Command prompt with "Run as administrator", then type `netstat -anb`.

Command runs faster in numerical form (`-n`), and the `-b` option requires elevation.

To filter the output and check only udp ports: use `netstat -anb -p udp`

Answer (score 3):

Windows Resource Monitor (not Widows performance monitor, or the monitor from the task manager) will also show the port and PID of all open connections.

Start --> Search --> "Resource Monitor" --> Netowrk tab

Answer (score 0):

Run `netstat –ano | find “0.0.0.0:22”` under the evaluated rights and get the process ID (number in the last column).

Then use Task Manager (Ctrl+Shift+Esc) to identify process. If it doesn't show PID column then turn it on (“View” > “Select Columns” > “PID (Process identifier)”)